# Why typeahead does not show results?

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead

I use this [plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

The HTML element is:

`<input class="form-control typeahead" maxlength="50" id="secondname" required="required" name="secondname" type="text">`

```
    $("#secondname").typeahead({
        minLength: 3,
        async: true,
        source: function (query, process) {
            return fetchPatientForm({ secondname: query })
                .then((res) => res.data)
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    return process(data);
                });
        },
    });
```

The response in

```
 console.log(data);
```

is:

`[{id: 39, name: 'Михаил', secondname: 'Попов', patronymic: '3' }];`

So there are no errors and result too. What do I do wrong?

I have tried to return plain array from server like [1, 2, 3] it also does not work

Comment: Curious why you're not following their async docs for an async source function: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets

Comment: Could you share an example? I use source but async